# How to make an interactive button in mayavi

Tags: mayavi

One of the mayavi examples shows how to make an interactive slider for a 3d display
http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_superquad_with_gui.html. 
Is there a similar way to make a button? (e.g. something the user can click on to change the picture shown.)